# `10/2` evaluates to `42279.00`?

Tags: string, excel, formatting, excel-formula, worksheet-function

In Excel, I have a cell value as number format, say `10/2`. It displays as `10/2` but I would like `5.00`.

It evaluates to `5.00` if I add an `=` before it i.e, `=10/2`, but I don't want to have to edit around 500 rows of that column.

I tried to use VALUE function but it evaluates it to `42279.00`:

Cell B1 `10/2`
Cell B2 `42279.00`

Another data example is: `100/20`.

Can you please tell me what has gone wrong, or is there any approach to get the cell value `10/2` to be evaluated to `5.00`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try applying a formula of the following kind to all your data:

```
=MONTH(B1)/DAY(B1)
```

Having done so you may select the results, Copy and Paste Special over their source (assumed to be ColumnB) and then delete the formulae.

Excel has, trying to be helpful, interpreted your entries as dates - the above should reverse the coercion.

---

Since now it seems not all entries have been coerced into dates, I suggest for those that have not:

```
=LEFT(B1,FIND("/",B1)-1)/MID(B1,FIND("/",B1)+1,LEN(B1))
```

Comment: Hi, It worked.Thanks will try to work it out for the entire row.

Comment: Sorry my mistake not to entire row but to the column. Like B2 is 10/3, B3 is 100/20 etc., containing all fractions

Comment: Ok, I tried to use an adjacent column and applied your suggested approach of just =month(b1)/day(b1) got my value and used the drag option to evaluate it for the entire column. Planning on hiding the actual column. Until we get a better approach.

Comment: But why did excel interpret it as date? in the first place

Comment: Thats it, You have given me the apt answer, Thanks a lot pnut, Wish you a Happy, Prosperous & a fun filled New Year :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you’re putting in what you’re thinking of as a calculation (ten divided by 2), but you’re not saying it’s a calculation (no “=”) so excel is looking at it as a value. When it looks at “10/2” it thinks “that’s a date, October second!” and it treats it as a date.

Dates are actually kept as numbers. If you had the column formatted as date or general, it could display as a date. But I’m guessing you have the column formatted as a number so it’s giving you the numeric representation of October 2, 2015.

The bad news is that as far as I know you would have to get the “=” in somehow, or do the calculation and replace it with 5 (10 divided by two would never be other than 5. If the latter you could select the column and do a replace 42279 with 5.

Comment: Yes I saw the Oct 2 value I get it now. but It was column & not rows, pnuts approach did work, thanks for the idea of replacing but that wouldn't have worked for me. :-)